# Trouble parsing HTML with BeautifulSoup or golang colly

Tags: python, go, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

FTR I have written quite a few scrapers successfully in both frameworks but  I'm stumped. Here is a screenshot of the data I'm trying to scrape (you can also go to the actual link in the get request):

[image]

I attempt to target the `div.section_content`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = requests.get("https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ARI/ARI201803300.shtml").text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
soup.findAll("div", {"class": "section_content"})
```

Printing the last line shows some other divs, but not the one with the pitching data.

However, I can see it's in the text, so it's not a javascript triggered loading problem (the phrase "Pitching" only comes up in that table):

```
>>> "Pitching" in soup.text
True
```

Here is an abbreviated version of one of the golang attempts:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "github.com/gocolly/colly"
) 

func main() {
    c := colly.NewCollector(
            colly.AllowedDomains("www.baseball-reference.com"),
    )   
    c.OnHTML("div.table_wrapper", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
            fmt.Println(e.ChildText("div.section_content"))
    })  
    c.Visit("https://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/ARI/ARI201803300.shtml")
```

}
    }

Comment: with javascript disabled the page is empty

Comment: that is false, did you see where I checked for the table header? `"Pitching" in soup.text`.

Comment: In the above example, `>>> len(soup.text)` prints `81995`. Doesn't seem empty...

Comment: @rofls: `soup.text` includes the comments, but bs4 will not find HTML inside comments.

Comment: there are 6 divs with selector `div.section_content`. pitching is in 2nd div. you have to do someting like `soup.findAll("div", {"class": "section_content"})[1]`. I recommend using ids `#div_ColoradoRockiespitching` ,`#div_ArizonaDiamondbackspitching` instead of `div.section_content`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks to me like the HTML is actually commented out, so that's why BeautifulSoup can't find it. Either remove the comment markers from the HTML string before you parse it or use BeautifulSoup to [extract the comments](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#extract) and parse the return value.

For example:

```
for element in soup(text=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment)):
    comment = element.extract()
    comment_soup = BeautifulSoup(comment)
    # work with comment_soup
```

Comment: I thought the comment ended right before that section

Comment: @rofls: A lot of code is commented out in the HTML, perhaps to prevent web scraping? ;)

Comment: Hahah, I think those comments are actually mostly popups over the column headers

Comment: As you can see in the above screenshot, it doesn't appear commented out (the green text before it ends the commented section)

Comment: @rofls: My friend I think you're mistaken, if I search for e.g. Tyler, it looks to me like what you're looking for is inside a comment.

Comment: ok let me take a closer look then and if this works i will accept your answer. thanks for the help so far